# Most different language from Zulu

Tags: language-families, zulu

Out of all languages in the world, through all language families on earth, of all 7,000 languages on the planet, which one has the most genetic distance from Zulu.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think this question is opinion-based—asking "which is the _closest_ language to Zulu" (or French or Japanese or…) is something that can be measured objectively, so asking for the _least_ close isn't really any less objective. It's just not really answerable with our current knowledge (and the answers below explain that).

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, the answer is going to be a many, *many*-way tie.

There are a lot of language families in the world that our current methods just aren't strong enough to show any connection between. We can say that Zulu is related to all the other Bantu languages, and more distantly related to all the other Atlantic-Congo languages, and even *more* distantly related to all the other Niger-Congo languages…and then we kind of hit a wall.

Because if there *is* a connection between Niger-Congo languages and (say) Indo-European languages, or Sino-Tibetan languages, or Uto-Aztecan languages, nobody has ever convincingly demonstrated it. We can make a guess as to how much contact they might have had, based on genetics and archaeology (human genetics, not language genetics), but there's no real way of saying that (e.g.) Nahuatl is more distantly connected than Mandarin, or Sumerian, or Basque. All of them are at the same level of "we can't show any convincing genetic relationship at all".

Answer (score 2):

We typically assume that all languages are related at some point in history, so the question would be, what extant language has a common ancestor reaching maximally far back in history. One good candidate would be the neighboring Tuu languages (Taa and !Kwi), or Kxʼa (Ju–ǂHoan). Because the question is beyond the reach of linguistic reconstruction, this would be based on archaeological considerations. We have reasonable evidence that the ancestors of all African languages other than so-called Khoisan were spoken in the general area of the Nile cataracts 12Kya or more, but Khoisan seems to derive from populations living in southern Africa at that time. Movement of Zulu into its present range is a relatively recent development, where differentiation of the various Nguni tribes took place over the past 500 years.

An alternative hypothesis would be to pick some random language not spoken in Africa, for example Burushaski, and posit that the ancestors of the Burushaski migrated out of Africa 40Kya whereas there was a common ancestor underlying all contemporary African languages and that the Khoisan people migrated south from Kenya or thereabouts and everybody else migrated north. There is no evidence whatsoever that suggests where the Burushaski came from that long ago (you can substitute "Chinese; Sentinelese..." and any other people, it's the same problem).

There are genetic arguments often offered in support of historical events, based on shared genetic mutations. One of the oldest genetic splits among humans is what's called the L0 haplogroup, the occurrence of which is highest in Africa and especially southern Africa among Khoisan people. Then there are other splits, haplogroups L1-6, which have various attestations in other parts of Africa, but also L3 which has strong attestation everywhere else. L3 is inherited by everybody else and is the architypical "out of Africa" genetic clade.

In other words, Khoisan diverged from "other African" first, and "non-African" diverged from African even later. Though, it is possible that Khoisan was spoken by people in the "other African" group, and later moved into southern Africa and their language spread to the indigenous population, so that genetic ancestry and linguistic ancestry are different.

Comment: Your first sentence is untrue. Although it makes theoretical sense, the base assumption of historical linguists is absolutely NOT that all languages are related since we can’t prove it empirically.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot really tell because we have no good distance measures for languages without demonstrated relationship.

But most linguists believe, that the Khoisan languages form an outgroup to all other extant languages of the world. So the most unrelated languages to Zulu are found in the geographic neighbourhood of it, and despite the fact that Zulu has acquired some features of them (like a rich inventory of click sounds), the most unrelated languages to Zulu are tied among the Khoisan languages.